# SpriteKit : Finding unexpectedly nil while unwrapping, can't implement multiple menu scenes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to present a menu with 2 buttons as initial scene: `play`, `credits`. When `play` is clicked, I want to present another menu scene with 4 buttons: `tutorial`, `easy`, `hard`, `back`. 
The strategy is simply to create the buttons as `SKSpriteNode` objects and handle clicks in `touchesBegan` function. 
In my `menuScene.sks` file I properly placed and named my nodes. Here, you can check the `menuScene.swift` file linked to this scene:

```
import SpriteKit

class menuScene: SKScene {

var playButton:SKSpriteNode!
var creditsButton:SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    playButton = self.childNode(withName: "playButton") as! SKSpriteNode
    creditsButton = self.childNode(withName: "creditsButton") as! SKSpriteNode
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // transition is defined in Helper.swift
    let touch = touches.first

    if let location = touch?.location(in: self){

        let nodesArray = self.nodes(at: location)

        if nodesArray.first?.name == "playButton" {
            let nextScene = difScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
        } else if nodesArray.first?.name == "creditsButton" {
            let nextScene = creditsScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run, menuScene is presented without a problem. However when I touch the `play` button I get an error and it is from next scene: `difScene`. 
Here you can find `difScene.swift`:

```
import SpriteKit

class difScene: SKScene {

var tutButton:SKSpriteNode!
var easyButton:SKSpriteNode!
var hardButton:SKSpriteNode!
var backButton:SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    tutButton = self.childNode(withName: "tutButton") as! SKSpriteNode // error
    easyButton = self.childNode(withName: "easyButton") as! SKSpriteNode
    hardButton = self.childNode(withName: "hardButton") as! SKSpriteNode
    backButton = self.childNode(withName: "backButton") as! SKSpriteNode
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let transition = SKTransition.push(with: .down, duration: 0.2)
    let touch = touches.first

    if let location = touch?.location(in: self){

        let nodesArray = self.nodes(at: location)
        if nodesArray.first?.name == "tutButton" {

            let nextScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
        }

        if nodesArray.first?.name == "easyButton" {
            let nextScene = difScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
        }

        if nodesArray.first?.name == "hardButton" {
            let nextScene = difScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
        }

        if nodesArray.first?.name == "backButton" {
            let nextScene = menuScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In case it may be useful, here is my `GameViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "menuScene") {

        // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
        if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! menuScene? {

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                view.showsFPS = false
                view.showsNodeCount = false
            }
        }
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know this is not a unique error. I have Google'd, watched tutorials and tried to derive a solution from other StackOverflow threads but failed to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on this line

```
tutButton = self.childNode(withName: "tutButton") as! SKSpriteNode // error
```

because there is no child node with the name "tutButton", so force casting it to an `SKSpriteNode` causes the error.

When the play button is pressed, you call this code:

```
let nextScene = difScene(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

This initializes a new `difScene` and presents it, which in turn calls the line of code above which is crashing.

Do you have a corresponding `sks` file for the `difScene` where you add the four buttons you reference in `didMove`?

If so, you'll need to initialize the `difScene` with the `sks` file like you did for your menu scene:

```
let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "difScene")
```

If not, you'll need to create those four button nodes and add them as children to your scene programatically.

---

**Side note:** In Swift, the convention is to name types starting with capital letters. Your `menuScene` should be `MenuScene`, and your `difScene` should be `DifScene`. This will make it much easier for others to read and understand your code.

Comment: Sorry that's a habit from my Java days... I have the corresponding difScene.sks file and all buttons are placed. Where exactly should I initialize my difScene in GameViewController?

Comment: @CevatMertDökümcü You can initializae it in the same place you are currently (`let nextScene = difScene(size: self.size)`), but you'll need to call the initializer with `fileNamed` instead of `size`.

Comment: Oh okay what should I do to resize after initializing? I have tried using " nextScene?.size = self.size " but it did not work. I am currently successfully proceeding to difScene but it is bigger than intended

Comment: @CevatMertDökümcü Are you setting the new scene's `scaleMode`? Use your code in `GameViewController.swift` as a reference.